# Attempt URL alias for spanish version of page - "The path */* is either invalid or you do not have access to it."

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

Drupal 7.59. We have the page whatever.tld/thanks and whatever.tld/es/thanks.
I'm trying to setup whatver.tlp/gracias as a URL alias for es/thanks and it says "The path 'es/thanks' is either invalid or you do not have access to it."

The page itself is a tpl.php file referred to by a view and has individual blocks on it that are translated.

This translation stuff is beyond me. I have a dev site to practice on so I'm happy to try out any ideas. The following (apparently) applicable modules are enabled:

- GTranslate
- Block languages
- Internationalization
- Menu translation
- Multilingual content
- String translation
- Translation sets

Comment: PHP Templates are there to dress up the output, but you're supposed to rely on Drupal engine to provide content for it. You should enable Languages you intend to use (you probably have) and translate your English Thanks page into Spanish. The Spanish node should contain the Spanish gracias content. You can use Pathauto to define special paths for languages if you need to. Blocks can also be language sensitive so when you translate block content through Drupal you don't have to place each language instance of a block separately by language...

Answer (score 0):

As @prkos mentioned enable the languages module. In the Configuration/Regional and language/Languages settings you select the code you wish to use for your languages. The choice is obviously yours but when I have a multilingual site I prefer to use the ISO language code to help define the languages on the site.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm not understanding part of your answer. I have Pathauto enabled but when I got to add a new alias from "es/thanks" and try to call it "gracias" (not a pattern -- and I'm not sure how those work) it gives me the above error.